# Data Storage Security

Tags: android, security

I want to keep the data secure.
Only accessible from my app,
I hope that even if you route Android, it is not accessible from the outside and can not be changed.

I am searching through `'FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput (FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);'`

Is this the best way?

Comment: It is not a question about access restrictions.
Security related questions.
This is to prevent specific data from being leaked from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

This will help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/access-modifiers.html

Access modifiers and ecapsulation help you prevent things from being access by other class/method or limit access to some classes/method.

But I believe in your case you would want to make your variable have access modifiers.
Write these variables on top of the class:

```
private FileOutputStream writetofile;// This variable is private and can only be accessed within the class.
private final String location; //This is the location of where you are saving to. Because it is final it will always save to that location
```